# How to insert Json into cassandra using API, QueryBuilder and batch

Tags: sql, cassandra, query-builder

I see that all examples for JSON uses the query as string like

```
String cqlStatement = "INSERT INTO users JSON '{\"id\":888 , \"age\":21 ,\"state\":\"TX\"}'";
```

but I want to use QueryBuilder, since I would like to insert in batch.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use Insert.json() method**

> Inserts the provided object, using the INSERT INTO ... JSON syntax introduced in Cassandra 2.2.

Example :

```
QueryBuilder.insertInto("my_data").json("{\"id\": 1, \"value\": \"This is a test\"}");
```

Note : Any columns which are omitted from the JSON string will be defaulted to a NULL value (which will result in a tombstone being created).