# Unable to insert json into cassandra via QueryBuilder in java

Tags: java, cassandra, query-builder

I am trying to insert json into cassandra using Querybuilder in java. 
Dependency that I have in my project is

```
"com.datastax.cassandra" % "cassandra-driver-core" % "3.0.0"
```

I referred to this post ([How to insert Json into cassandra using API, QueryBuilder and batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43236799/how-to-insert-json-into-cassandra-using-api-querybuilder-and-batch)) for inserting json, however the `.json()` method does not seem to exist in the queryBuilder class for me.

```
QueryBuilder.insertInto(KEYSPACE,TABLE).json(jsonData);
```

It gives me an error

```
cannot resolve symbol json
```

Is there any other method or way to insert json into cassandra using QueryBuilder methods ? Please let me know if I am missing something.
Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

The json function is available from [3.1 version](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.1/com/datastax/driver/core/querybuilder/Insert.html#json-java.lang.Object-). In [3.0](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.0/com/datastax/driver/core/querybuilder/Insert.html#method.summary) is not available.